# Openlayers Vector Layers eventListeners: how to specify different data without defining multiple layers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector

I have a map. It has two origins, and two destinations. The code for one origin is here:

```
vectors_origin = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Origin", {
            eventListeners:{
                    'featureselected':function(evt){
                    var feature = evt.feature;
                    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
                    OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
                    null,
                    json.orig1_iata_code.iata+"<br>",
                    null,
                    true,
                    null
                    );
                    popup.autoSize = true;
                    popup.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(400,800);
                    popup.fixedRelativePosition = true;
                    feature.popup = popup;
                    map.addPopup(popup);
            },
            'featureunselected':function(evt){
            var feature = evt.feature;
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            feature.popup = null;
            }
    }
    });
```

Note this line:

`json.orig1_iata_code.iata+"<br>",`

This takes care of one origin. Now since all 4 points (2 origins, 2 destinations), this HTML is going to differ a bit. There will be an

`orig1_iata_code`, `orig2_iata_code`, `dest1_iata_code`, and `dest2_iata_code`

I really don't want to have to define 4 separate vector layers. Sure it will work, but that seems pretty tacky (correct me if I'm wrong).

So where that html is called above, `json.orig1_iata_code.iata+"<br>",`, is there any way to specify 'multiple' optional parameters? Multiple I've done before, but all of them will be called every time.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What exactly are orig1_iata_code, orig2_iata_code...? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Is there an attribute that defines which point is what? How do you know to which point `orig1_iata_code` refers to?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. orig1_iata_code (and the other 3) are what should be displaying in the popup, which are airport codes (this being a map displaying airports). I came up with a solution: definitely not the most elegant but works. @Julien-SamuelLacroix the points are returned via json array in a php file, referenced in an ajax call in the OL file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your solution was, but if you can know what variable correspond to what point it could be as simple as:

```
'featureselected':function(evt){
    var feature = evt.feature;

    var popup_text = '<br>';
    if(feature.attributes.your_attribute == 'orig1') {
        popup_test = orig1_iata_code;
    } else if(feature.attributes.your_attribute == 'orig2') {
        popup_test = orig2_iata_code;
    } else if(feature.attributes.your_attribute == 'dest1') {
        popup_test = dest1_iata_code;
    } else if(feature.attributes.your_attribute == 'dest2') {
        popup_test = dest2_iata_code;
    }

    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
        OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
        null,
        popup_text,
        null,
        true,
        null
    );
    popup.autoSize = true;
    popup.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(400,800);
    popup.fixedRelativePosition = true;
    feature.popup = popup;
    map.addPopup(popup);
},
```